# Analysis involving closed intervals and rationality

Tags: analysis

Can someone help me prove this problem? Prove that every closed interval $[a,b]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains at least one rational number.

Comment: "dual of" [Analysis proof about irrational numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373169/analysis-proof-about-irrational-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac1{n}<b-a$ then for some $ m  \in \mathbb{Z}$ , we have  $\frac m{n}\in [a,b]$ ..